# Claiming resource with innodb using atomic update

Tags: mysql, innodb, atomic

If I have an InnoDB table that contains resources (e.g., URLs) that need to be processed (see below):

`RESOURCE_TABLE {
      id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      resource varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      process_id int DEFAULT NULL
   }`

where unprocessed resources have a process_id set to NULL, and there are multiple processes contending to claim each resource, can I do:

`update RESOURCE_TABLE set process_id={MY_PROCESS_ID} where process_id is NULL order by id ASC LIMIT 1;`

to claim a resource for a given process? Will this update be atomic, or do I need to create a transaction? Also if I claim a new resources in this way, will the resources be claimed sequentially without any gaps in ids?

This question is similar to: [MySQL Atomic UPDATE in InnoDB vs MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502135/atomic-update-in-innodb-vs-myisam)

Comment: Your linked question answer your first question. For the second, have you tried it?

Comment: Hi Mike, it's not quite the same - the other question specified a unique ID, whereas mine looks for rows with unclaimed resources. Also I'm interested in whether resources are claimed sequentially. Haven't tried it yet. What I'm really interested is what is happening under the hood, so to speak.